# Swapping Polymorphic Objects

Tags: c++

I have a base class A and derived class of B. What I want to be able to is to swap the objects they point to. Applying std::swap on the underlying base objects of the pointers only swaps the base object contents and not that of the derived object as well. How do I fix that to get std::swap to work properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


class A {
public:
    void setA(unsigned int value) { *a = value; }

    unsigned int getA() { return *a; }
    virtual void h(){}

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned int> a = std::make_unique<unsigned int>();
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void setB(unsigned int value) { *b = value; }

    unsigned int getB() { return *b; }

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned int> b = std::make_unique<unsigned int>();
};


int main() {

    std::unique_ptr<A> oA = std::make_unique<B>();
    oA->setA(100);

    auto a = dynamic_cast<B*>(oA.get());
    a->setB(30);


    std::unique_ptr<A> oB = std::make_unique<B>();
    oB->setA(1000);
    std::swap(*oA.get(), *oB.get());

    std::cout << dynamic_cast<B*>(oB.get())->getB() << std::endl;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<B*>(oA.get())->getB() << std::endl;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<B*>(oA.get())->getA() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make a virtual `swap` function?

Comment: Make swap virtual member. But what is supposed to happen should it encounter two objects of the same base, but different inherited types? Aren't you getting into some double dispatch problems here?

Comment: If two objects are of different sizes in memory (which is often the case for an instance of a base class and an instance of the derived class) then swapping is problematical.    You might try swapping *pointers* to the objects - for example, two `A *` variables, one pointing to an `A` and the other to a `B` - rather than swapping the objects themselves.  Ensure that the base class is properly polymorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, you have two `A*` variables (misleadingly) named `a` and `b`, both pointing to `B` objects. You want `std::swap(*a, *b)` to swap the full `B` objects. If you had a way to do it, what would you want it do if `a` was actually pointing to an object of type `A`?

You cannot swap `A` and `B` because the objects have different sizes. You would need to put 'B' object where 'A' used to be, but there is not enough room in the memory for that.

You can, of course, swap *pointers* themselves: `std::swap(a, b)` would work fine.